# How to Add records from classt type List to Class object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

hi friends i have list bellow

```
List<Authors>listAuthor=new  List<Authors>();
```

in that list i have 100 records, now my question is this i wanna to save these list into database only with one round trip(only one hit to database) in Asp.Net MVc using Database First Technique in Entity Framework

I have created object

```
  Author objAuthor=new Author();
  objAuthor=listAuthor;
```

i am getting conversion error,  any  idea  friends?

This  is  my full Code

```
    public ActionResult SaveAuthorConsol()
    {
        List<Author> listAuthor = new List<Author>(); // declare list

        List<Bib> bib = new List<Bib>(); // geting records from this table
        bib = db.Bibs.ToList();

        var q = db.Authors.ToList(); 

        foreach (var c in q)
        {
            db.Authors.DeleteObject(c); //Note:deleting previous records from Author table
        }

        db.SaveChanges();

        foreach (var bibitems in bib) // return Author type list 
        {
            Authors objAuthor = new Authors();
           listAuthor.AddRange(objAuthor.SaveAouthor(0, bibitems.Contents));
        }
        foreach (Author objauthor in listAuthor) //adding my list records to database
        {
            db.Authors.Attach(objauthor); //   getting error here
        }


        db.SaveChanges();
        return View();
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to create a new object of type `Author`. You can directly call SaveChanges once after adding each item to the database context.

Try:

```
foreach(Author objAuthor in listAuthor)
{
     db.Author.AddObject(objAuthor);
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: @Habib.. its `db.SubmitChanges()` instead of `SaveChanges()`

Comment: getting  this  error  "same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager"

Comment: @KapsHasija, what does your list contain ? are those new objects of type `Author` or you are getting them from the database ? if so, you can't add them back to the database

Comment: yes  i  am  getting from database but  not from Author table, records are coming from diff.  table and i am doing some filter  then saving to my list

Comment: @KapsHasija, you may add the code to your question where you are populating the list

Comment: @habib check my  edit  part..  Now you can  understand better

Comment: @KapsHasija, in your code you are using `Attach`, if you are inserting new records in `Author` table you need to call `Add` method, not attach

Comment: yes  i  have change Attach to Addobject becaouse i am using Database First  .. Now its  working Thanks @habib and  also to other guys

Answer (score 1):

You could add elements to the list:

```
List<Authors> listAuthor = new List<Authors>();
Author objAuthor = new Author();
listAuthor.Add(objAuthor);
```

But since you mentioned EF, I guess you have a database context to which you could directly add entities and persist the changes:

```
Author objAuthor = new Author();
db.Authors.Add(objAuthor);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: my records  in  list  as you mention above so to save in database i have move those records from list to object . I think now you clear  about my question

Comment: No, I am afraid your question is not clear. You have a list of records that you want to add to the db context? Then simply loop through this list and call the .Add method.

Comment: I want to save  only  one  hit  to database  so  can't use  for loop

Comment: You could use a for loop in order to copy the elements that you have in your existing context to the db context.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your way of conversion..Take a look at your code, what you are trying to do is..Assigning a `List<Authors>` to `Author` Class's Instance..Well its simply not possible..you have to do opposite of it..

**EDIT**
For multiple [Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387145.aspx) Unfortunately there is no way yet. What i can suggest you to do..prepare XML for your multiple rows. and use XML insert and use Regular Stored Procedure , by this way you can insert Any number of rows in one go and only in One Hit to DB.

Comment: thing  is  that  i  need  to  save  my  list  data   in a  database  only with  one round  trip...  i  can  use  any   way  ..  if  you  have  any idea then tell me